# Left Join with NOT IN clause and QueryBuilder

Tags: doctrine-orm, query-builder, dql

i'm trying to convert a query to DQL or build ir with query builder.
I can retrive with success the results from database with the following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM flag 
left join countries
on flag.id = countries.flag
where countries.flag IS NULL
```

Now, i need to conver this to DQL or build it with queryBuilder.
My entities are Country and Flag. The entity Country as a field flag as a external id.

So far, i got the following code:

```php
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$available =
    $qb
        ->select('f')
        ->from('Flag', 'f')
        ->leftJoin('Countries', 'c', 'ON', 'c.flag = f.id')
        ->where('f.id IS NULL');
```

My dump of $available doesnt return anything.
What's whong with this QueryBuilder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you also need to actually execute the query:

```php
$result = $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

that should give you the results.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
where('f.id IS NULL');
```

is wrong.

It should be

```sql
where('c.flag IS NULL');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.

Both answers are correct. Heres the final code, in case someone else search.
Also, i had to replace the 'ON' with 'WITH'.

```php
$available =
    $qb
        ->select('f')
        ->from('Flag', 'f')
        ->leftJoin('Countries', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.flag = f.id')
        ->where('c.flag IS NULL');
$flags = $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```